# Blank Page with Front End Template in Controller

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template, controllers

I have a controller that needs to display text, but I get a blank page. Here is what I have:

> Controller/Index/Index.php

```
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {

        protected $_resultPageFactory;

        public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
        {
            $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            return $resultPage;
        }
    }
```

> Block/Ageverification.php

```
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Block;

    class Ageverification extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
      private $scopeConfig;
      protected $messageManager;

      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager)
      {

        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;

      }

      public function getAgeVerificationText()
      {
        $fail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('veratad/general/failuretext', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $this->messageManager->addError( __("$fail") );
      }
    }
```

> view/frontend/layout/ageverification_index_index.xml

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Veratad\AgeVerification\Block\Ageverification" name="ageverification" template="ageverification.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> view/frontend/templates/ageverification.phtml

```
    <h3><?php echo $this->getAgeVerificationText(); ?></h3>
```

When i navigate to the controller I get a white page with no error messages. Can someone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try change the file view/frontend/layout/ageverification_index_index.xml to utf8 type then clear cache and check result

Comment: @Thomas  in which mode you are using the magento ? please check using bin/magento deploy:mode:show and if it is in production mode change it to developer mode using  bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer and try  .

Answer (score 1):

Update the `__construct()` function in your block file.

> Block/Ageverification.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
) {

    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not work.

Comment: Is there any `exit;` statement somewhere in your code?. Try to find out.

Answer (score 0):

do following changes in **view/frontend/layout/ageverification_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Veratad\AgeVerification\Block\Ageverification" name="ageverification" template="Veratad_AgeVerification::ageverification.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```